# WebStorm not suggesting/autocompleting code for styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, webstorm, styled-components

I've recently switched from VSCode to WebStorm. But I noticed that WebStorm doesn't suggest attributes and props on styled-components like VSCode. It does suggest for normal HTML/JSX though. Has anyone else had problems with it and know how to fix it?

I've installed types for react, react-native, react-dom, styled-system, and styled-components as this has been suggested before, but with no luck.

VSCode:
[image: An example from VSCode]

Exact same code from the exact same project in WebStorm:
[image: Exact same code from the exact same project in WebStorm]

VSCode even suggests props from Styled System, which WebStorm seems incapable of. I really like WebStorm, but this issue is making me wonder if I should switch back.

2020 MacBook Pro if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Install the webstorm-styled-components plugin

https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#webstorm-intellij-idea-phpstorm-pycharm-and-rubymine
https://github.com/styled-components/webstorm-styled-components

> To install the plugin open the IDE Preferences | Plugins, then click Browse repositories... and search for Styled Components.

Comment: Okay.  The reason VSC seems to work out of box, is because the Babel plugin for VSC already includes styled-components support

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, as far as I'm able to tell I might have to eject from create-react-app to change the babel config to run the plugin. I find it interesting that this works so well out of the box with VSC and not Webstorm, as Webstorm usually seems more "complete" out of the box.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I have the style components plugin installed and still not getting any suggestions

Comment: works for me in one project and not the other...

Answer (score 0):

Just Install The @types/styled-components package. Its not getting type information Thats whats happening.